# Uncaught SyntaxError while dynamically generating a select field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have an issue with my `append` function. I was trying to show an image within a select `option` by using values from a database which works fine but users can add more `option`s dynamically by generating a select `option` using the `append` function - but I'm getting this error;

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list...

Here's the code that works fine;

```
<select data-show-subtext="true" class=" selectpicker bs-select form- 
  control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="city">    
   <option value=""></option>    
   <?php foreach($get_drawing as $row):  $image=$row->image;  ?> 
   <option data-subtext="<img width='28%' height='90%''  src='<?=base_url("drawing/fabricator/admin_3/".$row->image);?>'>"  
value="<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>"  >
 <?php echo $row->drawing_name;?> 
</option>
```

And here's the `append` code:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    j++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+j+'" class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;"><hr><div class=col-sm-1 form-group-sm" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+j+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div><div class="col-sm-2  form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Drawing</label>   <select data-show-subtext="true" class=" selectpicker bs-select form-control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="city"><option value=""></option><?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  ?><option data-subtext=<img width='28%' height='90%''  src='<?=base_url("drawing/fabricator/admin_3/".$row->image);?>'>" value="<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>"  ><?php echo $row->drawing_name;?>  </option><?php endforeach; ?></select></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Type</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control sm" name="type" value="22"/> </div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Profile Series</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="pf"/> </div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Location</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="location"/></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Width</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="width"/> </div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Height</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="height"/> </div> <div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Quantity</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="quantity"/> </div>                                                                         <div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Fixed</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_height"/><br><input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_width"/></div></div>');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');          
        });
```

According to my knowledge the problem is with this line but I don't know how to correct the code in my `append` function because if I change it, it doesn't work.

```
  data-subtext="<img width='28%' height='90%''  src='<?=base_url("drawing/fabricator/admin_3/".$row->image);?>'>"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have multiple `'` inside your append. It might be making problems for you, like `width='28%'`

Comment: corrected this but problem still exist

Comment: you have so many typos its hard to count, missing `"` missing `'` everywhere and spaces in class names when their shouldn't be. go through your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#add').click(function(){
    j++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row"'+j+'" class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;"><hr><div class=col-sm-1 form-group-sm" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+j+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div><div class="col-sm-2  form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Drawing</label>   <select data-show-subtext="true" class=" selectpicker bs-select form-control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="city"><option value=""></option><?php  foreach($get_drawing as $row):  ?><option data-subtext="<img width="28%" height="90%"  src="'<?=base_url('drawing/fabricator/admin_3/'.$row->image);?>'">" value="<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>"  ><?php echo $row->drawing_name;?>  </option><?php endforeach; ?></select></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Type</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control sm" name="type" value="22"/> </div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Profile Series</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="pf"/> </div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Location</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="location"/></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Width</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="width"/> </div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Height</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="height"/> </div> <div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Quantity</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="quantity"/> </div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Fixed</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_height"/><br><input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_width"/></div></div>');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');          
        });
```

Replace your append function to this. You had misplaced single quotes which were breaking the string.

Comment: There are still single quotes in the append `>image);?>'>"`

Comment: dude i copied and pasted your code but stil getting this error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list but when i remove data-subtext="" the error gone away

Comment: please help me out to set syntax for data-subtext=" "

Comment: still no success bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#dynamic_field').append('<hr><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:10px;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + j + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Drawing</label><select data-show-subtext="true" class="selectpicker bs-select form-control" data-live-search="true" data-size="8" name="city"><option value=""></option><?php foreach ($get_drawing as $row): ?><option data-subtext="<img width="28%" height="90%" src="<?= base_url("drawing/fabricator/admin_3/" . $row->image); ?>">" value="<?php echo $row->drawing_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->drawing_name; ?></option><?php endforeach; ?></select></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Type</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" name="type" value="22"/></div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Profile Series</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="pf"/></div><div class="col-sm-2 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Location</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="location"/></div><div class="col-sm-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Width</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="width"/></div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Height</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="height"/></div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"><label class="control-label">Quantity</label><input type="text" placeholder="Bed Front" class="form-control" value="22" name="quantity"/></div><div class="col-md-1 form-group-sm"> <label class="control-label">Fixed</label><input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_height"/><br><input type="text" placeholder="Height" class="form-control" value="" name="fixed_width"/></div></div>');
```

Your code is extremely difficult to read, perhaps separate it into parts.